# Fileupload control value becomes null multifile.js

Tags: javascript, multifile-uploader

I am using jquery.MultiFile.js for uploading the file with asp:FileUpload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuFileUpload" runat="server" maxlength="1"
ContentEditable="false" />
```

I am accessing the uploaded file using following java script code

```
var elem = document.getElementById("<%=fuFileUpload.ClientID%>");
var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elem.files.length; ++i) {
   names.push(elem.files[i].name);
}
```

---

Which will work properly as expected.

Problem:
Problem is that when we upload the file then remove the file with (x) button provided in jquery.MultiFile.js. and again upload the file.

### elem variable

getting null in this case.

Please Help

What I have tried:

tried to get file in jquery with

```
// Get posted files 
var files = $("#<%=fuFileUpload.ClientID %>").get(0).files;
```

---

Comment: If you inspect the `<input>` element in browser you can check its ID. Does it change when you remove and re-add a file?

Comment: Thanks for Help. As per your suggestion i inspect <input> element. And found the reason for the issue. When removing the file and re-adding the file file upload control ID changes to fuFileUpload_F1. Resolve this issue by using class selector. So now i accessing the file using the javascript var files = $(".MultiFile-applied").get(0).files;